# How to iterate through Dictionary of Dictionary Values in UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift

This is my first post and I hope its a great question because iv been stuck on this for days. (Literally searched every related question and found nothing that I could add up for a solution.)

Basically I'm building a pure Swift application. My problem is that I cant figure out how to place each dictionary values into each UITableCell that is created.

Also the `JSON` response from the `GET` creates a **`NSCFDictionary`** type.

UITableViewCell Properties

- UILabel - Holds the Offer "name"
- UI Label #2 - Holds Offer "description"
- UIImage - Holds the Offer "thumb_url"

So basically I need to store each `offer` object's `(name, description, thumb_url)` in every `UITableViewCell` that the `ViewController` creates.

`GET Request`

```
import UIKit

class freeIAPCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var aName: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var aDescription: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var aImage: UIImageView!



}

class FreeIAPViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    // Everbadge Request

    var apiURL = "apiurlhere"

    var parsedArray: [[String:String]] = []

    func queryEB() {

        // Query  DB Here

        // Store the API url in a NSURL Object
        let nsURL = NSURL(string: apiURL)

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: nsURL!)

        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

        // Execute HTTP Request

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(nsURL!) {
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil {
                print("Error = \(error)")
                return
            }

            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

            do {
                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments) as! NSDictionary

                print(json.isKindOfClass(NSDictionary)) // true

                let data = json.objectForKey("data") as! NSDictionary
                //print(data)
                let m = data.objectForKey("offers") as! NSArray
                print(m)
                print(m.valueForKeyPath("name"))
                self.parsedArray = m as! [[String : String]]


            } catch {
                print("THERE WAS AN ERROR PARSING JSON FOR EVERBADGE")
            }


        }
        task.resume()

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        queryEB()




    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)


    }

    // MARK: UITableView method implementation

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("freeAppCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! freeIAPCell

        let obj = parsedArray[indexPath.row] // fatal error: Index out of range
        cell.aName.text = obj["name"]
        return cell
    }


}
```

`API Request Data Structure` (print(m))

```
( 
              {
                "name" = "Mate";
                id = 23941;
                description = "10-20 word description goes here"
                "url" = "google.com
                "ver" = "0.12"
                price = "0.17"
                "public_name" = "Good Ole Mate"
                "thumb_url" = "http://google.com/mate.jpg
          };
           {
                "name" = "Mate";
                id = 23941;
                description = "10-20 word description goes here"
                "url" = "google.com
                "ver" = "0.12"
                price = "0.17"
                "public_name" = "Good Ole Mate"
                "thumb_url" = "http://google.com/mate.jpg
          };
          {
                "name" = "Mate";
                id = 23941;
                description = "10-20 word description goes here"
                "url" = "google.com
                "ver" = "0.12"
                price = "0.17"
                "public_name" = "Good Ole Mate"
                "thumb_url" = "http://google.com/mate.jpg
          };
           {
                "name" = "Mate";
                id = 23941;
                description = "10-20 word description goes here"
                "url" = "google.com
                "ver" = "0.12"
                price = "0.17"
                "public_name" = "Good Ole Mate"
                "thumb_url" = "http://google.com/mate.jpg
          };
           {
                "name" = "Mate";
                id = 23941;
                description = "10-20 word description goes here"
                "url" = "google.com
                "ver" = "0.12"
                price = "0.17"
                "public_name" = "Good Ole Mate"
                "thumb_url" = "http://google.com/mate.jpg
          };
);
```

Comment: It looks like You need to use the `offers` array. You simply store this array and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you can use `indexPath.row` to access the array and retrieve the relevant offer dictionary. What do you get from the `print(y)` output?

Comment: Hello Paul! So iv been tinkering away while I wait for input and I'v updated the code to what I have now. Now im able to get into the offers dictionary but as you can see in "print(m)" It prints all the "offers" objects but no longer has key name "offer" for each object. How can I seperate each object for each UITableCell? Thank you!

Comment: So, it looks like m is now your array, so in cellForRowAtIndexPath you can use `m[indexPath.row]` to get the dictionary

Comment: Awesome :) your a genius! Do you know how I can make "m" available to the cellForRowAtIndexPath function? Do I have too create a struct in a different classes and then save "m" to that struct and then use that struct in the function?

Comment: You need m to be saved to a property of your class instance.

Comment: Ah ok. So i made that variable (Iv added the full code above). I used var parsedArray: [[String: String]] = [ ]  but its saying Index out of Range..maybe that variable has the wrong type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create public arrays for your 3 items...

```
var nameArray = [String]()
var descriptionArray = [String]()
var thumbnailArray = [String]()
```

Then loop through your json parse like this....

```
 let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! NSDictionary
    if responseString != nil
    {
        let items: AnyObject! = responseString["items"] as AnyObject!
        if items != nil
        {
            // Loop through all search results and keep just the necessary data.
            for var i=0; i<items.count; ++i
            {

                if let names = items[i]["name"] as? NSDictionary
                {
                    let name = names as! String
                    self.nameArray.append(name)
                }
                if let descriptions = items[i]["description"] as? NSDictionary
                {
                    let description = descriptions as! String
                    self.descriptionArray.append(description)
                }
                if let thumbnails = items[i]["thumb_url"] as? NSDictionary
                {
                    let thumbnail = thumbnails as! String
                    self.thumbnailArray.append(thumbnail)
                }
            }
        }
        self.resultsTableView.reloadData()
```

Create an OfferTableViewCell Class with a nameLabel:`UILabel`, descriptionLabel:`UILabel`, and thumbnailImage:`UIImage`. Finally in your cellForRowAtIndexPath.....

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("offer", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! OfferTableViewCell
        cell.nameLabel.text = self.nameArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.descriptionLabel.text = self.descriptionArray[indexPath.row]
        let url = NSURL(string: self.thumbnailArray[indexPath.row])
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
        cell.thumbnailImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)

        return cell

    }
```

Comment: You are a beast! Thank you!